# Group rows with for loop based on if statement and add new column

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe, grouping

I have got the following code and I need to adjust it as the output is not 100% correct:

```
df = read.table(text='colA   colB   colC
                10  11   7
                10  34   7
                10  89   7
                10  21   7
                9   8    0
                9   11   0
                9   21   0
                2   23   5
                2   21   5
                2   56   5
                1   45   0
                1   23   0
                22  14   3
                22  19   3
                22  90   3
                11  19   2
                11  45   2
                80  13   2
                80  17   2
                99  15   1
                55  20   1', header = TRUE)

df$ID <-NA

df[1,'ID']<-1

val=1

for (i in 2:nrow(df)){

  if (df[i,'colC']!=0 & (df[i,'colC']!=df[i-1,'colC'])) {val=val+1} 
  df[i,'ID']<-val

}
```

Output as per above code:

```
> df
   colA colB colC ID
1    10   11    7  1
2    10   34    7  1
3    10   89    7  1
4    10   21    7  1
5     9    8    0  1
6     9   11    0  1
7     9   21    0  1
8     2   23    5  2
9     2   21    5  2
10    2   56    5  2
11    1   45    0  2
12    1   23    0  2
13   22   14    3  3
14   22   19    3  3
15   22   90    3  3
16   11   19    2  4
17   11   45    2  4
18   80   13    2  4
19   80   17    2  4
20   99   15    1  5
21   55   20    1  5
```

What is wrong are the last 4 `ID` values, which should group the rows based on `colC` but because there are no 0s between each distinct group, `colC` values with same number but diverse `colA` are grouped together and this is not what I want.

Desired output (see last 4 `ID` values):

```
> df
   colA colB colC ID
1    10   11    7  1
2    10   34    7  1
3    10   89    7  1
4    10   21    7  1
5     9    8    0  1
6     9   11    0  1
7     9   21    0  1
8     2   23    5  2
9     2   21    5  2
10    2   56    5  2
11    1   45    0  2
12    1   23    0  2
13   22   14    3  3
14   22   19    3  3
15   22   90    3  3
16   11   19    2  4
17   11   45    2  4
18   80   13    2  5
19   80   17    2  5
20   99   15    1  6
21   55   20    1  7
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your condition a little, since different `colA` values make new IDs, `colA` needs to be included in the condition:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(df)){   
    # check the difference of colA here
    if (df[i,'colC']!=0 & (df[i,'colA']!=df[i-1,'colA'])) {val=val+1} 
    df[i,'ID']<-val    
}

df$ID
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 7
```

Or you can vectorize it as:

```
df$ID <- with(df, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(colA) != 0 & colC[-1] != 0)))
df$ID
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 7
```

Comment: thank you, may God or someone with his powers bless you. thanks

Comment: Has been a week that I was struggling with the above code. thank you again.

Comment: Glad it helps !

Comment: I also have this question open: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080667/r-how-to-add-parsapply-within-a-code and it would save me a lot of time...thank you